# リストの中の、リストの値を抽出するには

Tags: python, python3

基本的な質問にて失礼します。
以下のリストの中から、０番目のリストの中の、さらにインデックス０の値を**一行のコード**で取得するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。よろしく、お願いいたします。

```
lst=[[12,18,30],[12,18,30],[24,36,60]]

# やったこと: 2行のコードではできました。
lst0=lst[0]
lst0[0]

# 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いわゆる「多次元配列」などと呼ばれるもので、以下の通り参照すれば実現と思います。

```py
print (lst[0][0])
# 12
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。できました！